# how to return json response in laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

**this is my controller:**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $items = Post::latest()->paginate(5);
        $cmnt = Comment::all();

        return response()->json(array('posts'=>$items,'comment'=>$cmnt));
    }
```

**this my ajax request**

```
function getPageData() {
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "{{route('post_status.index')}}",
        data: {page:1}
      }).done(function(data){
            manageRow(data.data);
      });
    }
function manageRow(data) {
          console.log(data.comment);
}
```

why i am getting error ??
help me out of this plzz

Comment: "why i am getting error" __What__ error?

Comment: actually it shows me nothing.....no value at all

Comment: @leo have you tried looking in the console? Also in your comment on the answer you say something about multiple objects? Could you actually explain what you are trying to do in your question?

Comment: i want to return $items and $cmnt this two object from my controller using ajax response

Answer (score 6):

laravel returns json by default if it doesn't return view, in your case index() should return:

```
return ['posts' => $items,'comment' => $cmnt];
```

also I don't think this is correct

```
{{route('post_status.index')}}
```

probably should be

```
{{ url('post_status/index') }}
```

Comment: route is ok when i return one object it works well but when i want to return multiple object it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type of response from the server.

```
function getPageData() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "{{route('post_status.index')}}",
      type: 'GET'
      data: {page:1}
    }).done(function(data){
        manageRow(data.data);
    });
}

function manageRow(data) {
    console.log(data.comment);
}
```